# Help in ruby code

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am beginner in Ruby and having trouble understanding this code

```
    require_relative 'custom_page'

module Jekyll   
  class Tag < CustomPage
    def initialize(site, base, dir, tag)
      super site, base, dir, 'tag'

      self.data['tag'] = tag
      self.data['title'] = "#{site.config['tag_title_prefix'] || 'Tag: '}#{tag}"
      self.data['description'] = "#{site.config['tag_meta_description_prefix'] || 'Tag: '}#{tag}"
    end
  end

  class Tags < CustomPage
    def initialize(site, base, dir)
      super site, base, dir, 'tags'
      self.data['tags'] = site.categories.keys.sort
      #1# puts self.data['tags']
    end
  end

  class Site
    # generate_tags_categories is called by the custom process function in site_process.rb

    def generate_tags_categories            
      dir = self.config['tag_dir'] || 'tags'
      write_page Tags.new(self, self.source, dir) if self.layouts.key? 'tags'        

      self.categories.keys.each do |tag|
      puts "dd"
      #2# puts tag    
      write_page Tag.new(self, self.source, File.join(dir, tag.slugize), tag)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In the above code, the statement `puts self.data['tags']` (marked 1) outputs more than 10 values as expected. However, the line `puts tag` (marked 2) outputs only one value implying that array contains only one value. Isn't `self.categories.keys.each` expected to loop through all the values which itself is assigned to `self.data['tags']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may start with ensuring that the 'categories' *still* contain many values before entering the loop:

```
puts "categories.keys: #{self.categories.keys.inspect}" # <<- here
self.categories.keys.each do |tag|
  puts "dd"
  #2# puts tag
```

If the first `puts` shows you more than one value, and the loop is called only once, then you may want to investigate what possibly makes the loop break. Maybe `write_page` throws an exception, catch somewhere up the calling stack?

When you debug some values, it's better to use `inspect` method instead of (automagically called by `puts`) method `to_s`. The output of `inspect` is more debug-friendly.

It is possible, (however unlikely) that the 'tag' contains some control characters which clear the previous output, or something like that. The `inspect` is always safe. *(ok, not always but in most of cases ;)*